# CSS block link - how to get it work properly?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to use CSS block links in my web site.  I want to have light background with white fonts when the link is passive and dark background with white fonts when you hover over the link or if the link is active (the left button pressed but not released).  And I don’t want the font color to change. I’ve tried this on IE9, FF 7, Chrome 17 with the following code:

```
<!--
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<<style type="text/css">
a.header:link {
text-align:center;
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
font-color:white;
background:lightgreen;
width:112px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
outline-style:double;
outline-color:green;
}
a.header:hover,a:active {
background-color:darkgreen;
text-align:center
font-color:white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1><a class="header" href="http://www.vk.com">www 999</a></h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the code’s behaviour is unpredictable.  Font color is always dark (I want white), sometimes red if the link is active and the background is changing different way on different browsers
Can somebody help me to make this work the same way on popular browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There is no such thing as `font-color`. The name of the property is `color`.
- You have an extra `<` before `<style`.
- You shouldn't put your DTD in a comment; that defeats the point.
- There's a missing semicolon after `text-align: center`.
- You probably don't want to specify `:link`; that will *only* apply to links that are neither visited, hovered nor active.

[Here's a demo with all the fixes](http://jsbin.com/igefuc/edit#preview) on JSBin, because jsFiddle is down.

Comment: Thanks, it was correct in the original code, I've changed color to font-color because I couldn't get white fonts.

Comment: @user985456: Then your problem is most likely `:link`. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

1. "color", not "font-color"
2. You're missing the ".header" on the active state, "a:active".
3. You don't need the ":link" psuedo-selector on your first "a.header" rule
4. Extra "<" in the "